# Integrating jquery tipsy plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I'm trying to integrate tipsy plugin. But its not working.,
I already using another jquery plugin.
Its called orbit slider.
Project page [Orbit slider](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider)

This is the tipsy home page
[Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)

I'm trying to integrate tipsy below the navigation slider buttons.
Check this page.
[Tipsy problem](http://girisoft.net/tipsyproblem/)

I need tipsy integrated below those 7 bullets.
Those bullets are from previous orbit slider.
This is the modified orbit plugin js code.

Here is the cource code.[Source code](http://girisoft.net/tipsyproblem/js/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js)

The problem is when i click view source i'm not seeing source code of those bullets. Because html are coded within javascript.
They are not appear in the html source. So tipsy plugin not recognizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your source, try combining the scripts in your `<body>` tag into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
     $('#featured').orbit({

      'timer': false, 

      'bullets' : true, 
      'captions': true, 

      'bulletThumbs': true,

          'bulletThumbLocation': 'orbit/'

     });

     $("ul.orbit-bullets li").tipsy({gravity: 'n'});
});
</script>
```